# How to plot the S&P500 and its SMA in two different windows and in one window

Tags: python-3.x

I try to plot the S&P500 and its SMA in two different window with the folling codes. But it seems it doesn't work well. If I plot only one of them, it is OK.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import talib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1)

## S&P 500
sp500 = web.DataReader("SP500", "fred", start)
head = sp500[-100:].dropna()
print(len(head))
## Transform DataFrame to nparray
my_array = head.as_matrix()
## Transform column to row
x = my_array.T[0]
## Get rid off the NaN
y = x[~np.isnan(x)] 
print(len(y))
## Compute SMA
my_sma=talib.SMA(y, timeperiod=5)
print(len(my_sma))

## Plot
pyplot.figure(1)
pyplot.subplot(211) ## upper window
head.plot(use_index=False)

pyplot.subplot(212)  ## lower window
pd.Series(my_sma).plot(use_index=False)
```

And here is the plotting.

And besides, I want to plot them in the same window, i.e. oberlay.

[image]

Sorry that I have to change a lillte bit my codes so that it is more well-formed and one can better understand what I mean.

```
start = datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1)

def computeSMA(data):
    head = data[-100:].dropna()
    ## Transform column to row
    x = head.as_matrix().T[0]
    ## Get rid off the NaN
    y = x[~np.isnan(x)] 
    ## Compute SMA
    my_sma=talib.SMA(y, timeperiod=5)

    return my_sma

## S&P 500
sp500 = web.DataReader("SP500", "fred", start)
sp_sma = computeSMA(sp500)

## Plot
pyplot.figure(1)
sp500[-100:].dropna().plot()

pyplot.figure(2)
pd.Series(sp_sma).plot(use_index=False)
```

If I run the code, I got the error as follow:

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 401, in num2date
return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 254, in _from_ordinalf
dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

If I comment the plotting of figure(2), I will get plotting shown[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAo6L.png):

[image]

If I comment the plotting of figure(1), I will get the plotting shown [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5hR0.png):

[image]

Besides, I want to plot the SP500 and its SMA on the same figure and with the Date in X-axis.

Answer (score 0):

To plot two series on the same plot (note that this works for any number of time series):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

# Generate sample series (in your case these are s1=head and s2=pd.Series(my_sma) 
s1 = pd.Series([1, 3, 8, 10])
s2 = pd.Series([2, 4, 9, 11])

# Create the plot.
pyplot.figure()
pyplot.plot(s1)
pyplot.plot(s2)
pyplot.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: My question is:Why the first plotting can not be seen. If I comment the second plotting, the first plotting can be seen. Besides, the first is not a Series but a DF. I wonder how to plot different typy in the same window?